# GIT - how to show git log only commit at branch

Tags: git

```
A-->B-->C-->D-->E  (master)
    \->X-->Y-/-->Z (debug)
```

Hi all
if try

```
    git log master..debug
```

then I get Z only, because X, Y were merged to master branch.
briefly, ***i wanna get all log/commit where committed at debug branch***

Comment: Since X and Y have been already merged into master, you can't know what exactly these commits are from.

Comment: thanks, is any way to get the X,Y,Z??

Answer (score 1):

Use the `..` notation, e.g. like this:

```
git log master..feature
```

This lists all commits that are reachable from *feature* and excludes commits which are reachable from *master*. In other words, it lists commits that are "only" on *feature*.

Comment: Thanks, in your suggestion, i try `git log master..debug` in above case, and only get `Z`. However `X`,`Y` are not shown because X,Y were merged to `master`...

Answer (score 0):

```
git log parent_branch..new_branch
```

Comment: i tried, but it only show those commits where not merged to `parent_branch`. as above case, it will show `Z`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying the range.

Let's say hash for X is abcd123 and Y is dcba321.

You can call:

```
git log abcd..dcba
```

This will show you the range. You you can truncate the hash, as long as it stays unique (e.g. use the first few chars).

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, you want all the commits on the debug branch, since it originally diverged from master?  B is the parent of the debug branch, so try,

`git log B..debug`